# How to work with base-16 integers in C

Tags: c

I'm attempting to write a program where I need to use base-16 integers to determine a 1-bit error detection using C. However, I am unsure how C treats base-16 integers. I must first extract the lower order 16-bits from stdin. I need to use the scanf() function to read the first 16-bits from stdin and then store the numbers in an array of char (my code does not account for this at the moment). When I'm just simply testing my program to see if it would print the integer in 16-bit form, it only prints the 0 before the x if I enter a base-16 number such as 0xcd789f. Here is my code so far. It's just a standard "read an integer from stdin and print it to stdout" program so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num;

    scanf("%d", &num);  
    printf("%d\n", num);

    getchar();
}
```

This code will not work properly with a base-16 number. How do I account for this? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scanf("%x", &num);  
printf("%x %d\n", num, num);
```

Whether the number is represented in binary, octal, decimal or hex - the value of the number remains the same. This is shown by the print - it will print the value of the number in hex(base16) form and also in decimal form.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using `%x` in the `scanf` format string, you can use `strtol` to convert your input.

```
int num;
char buf[256];

if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) == 0) exit(0);
/* handles decimal, 0x prefix for hex, or 0 prefix for octal */
num = strtol(buf, 0, 0);
/* handles hex only, with or without 0x prefix */
num = strtol(buf, 0, 16);
```

To print out in hex, as stated elsewhere, you should use the `%x` conversion specifier. If you want the letters of the hex output to be in uppercase, use `%X` instead. If you want the output to have `0x` or `0X` in the prefix, you can use the `#` modifier to the conversion specifier.

```
printf("hex: %x %#x\nHEX: %X %#X\ndec: %d\n", num, num, num, num, num);
```